# Mongo Join String Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am writing an application to consume the data in my Mongo database, but I need to process the data in a flat format.  My document has a few arrays in it that I would like to turn into a string array, but can't find a way to do so with a mongo query.

Document:

```
{
  name: 'Hello World',
  tags: ['simple', 'easy']
}
```

Desired Output:

```
{
  name: 'Hello World',
  tags: 'simple,easy',
}
```

Comment: I think you'd need to use `mapReduce` to do that.  Probably better to do that client-side if possible.

Comment: Why not just do it as you retrieve the documents?

Comment: What @WiredPrairie said. Just use `toString()`.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done natively in MongoDB aggregation with `$reduce`:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{
  $set: {
     tags: {
       $reduce: {
         input: "$tags",
         initialValue: "",
         in: {
           $concat : ["$$value", "," ,"$$this"]
         }
       }
     }
  }, {
  $project: {
     name: 1,
     tags: { $substr: [ "$tags", 1, -1 ] }
  }
}]);
```

There is no way to avoid extra separator (leading or trailing) when using `$concat`, so there is additional step with `$substr` to remove it.

1. `$concat : ["$$value", "," ,"$$this"]` produces string `",a,b,c,d"`
2. `$substr: [ "$tags", 1, -1 ]` makes substring starting at index `1` with length `-1`, which is "as much as possible" in this context.

Also see documentation for [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/), [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/), [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/).

Answer (score 1):

This is very doable with one stage. addFields will overwrite the $tags element since it already exists. [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pjowUIvaLt3)

```
{
"$addFields": {
  "tags": {
    "$reduce": {
      "input": "$tags",
      "initialValue": "",
      "in": {
        "$concat": [
          //add the running concatination of this array to the front
          "$$value",
          //add the current value after that
          "$$this",
          {
            //comma. if current index is the last element, don't add a comma to the end.
            $cond: {
              if: {
                "$eq": [
                  {
                    $subtract: [
                      {
                        $size: "$tags"
                      },
                      1
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $indexOfArray: [
                      "$tags",
                      "$$this"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              then: "",
              else: ","
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of achieve this using a aggregation query is below but its very static.

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$tags" },
    { $group: { _id: "$_id", name: {$first: "$name"}, firstTag: {$first: "$tags"}, lastTag: {$last: "$tags"} } },
    { $project: { name: "$name", tags: { $concat: [ "$firstTag", ",", "$lastTag" ] } } }
]);
```

You can however achive this with a mapReduce:

```
db.test.mapReduce(
   function() {emit(this._id, this);},
   function(key, value) {return value}, {   
      out:"tags",
      finalize: function(key, reducedVal){
            reducedVal.tags = reducedVal.tags.join();
            return reducedVal;
      }
   }
)

> db.tags.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5849a9f6a4db9c5811299d08"), "value" : { "name" : "Hello World", "tags" : "simple,easy" } }
```